# Tracking white areas in an image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have an image with white circles outlined by black borders. I want to measure the size of the white circles using some form of software. I have been trying but having no luck. Here is my current code without attempted annotations being added:

```
import cv2
from scipy import ndimage
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename),0)
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
    return images

rawframes=load_images_from_folder('BubbleSize/90FoamQuality/DryFoams')

blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(rawframes[0],1,200,200)
blur = cv2.Canny(blur,60,60)

blur = ndimage.binary_dilation(blur)
blur = ndimage.binary_dilation(blur)
blur = ndimage.binary_dilation(blur)
blur = ndimage.binary_dilation(blur)
blur = ndimage.binary_dilation(blur)
blur = ndimage.binary_dilation(blur)
blur = ndimage.binary_erosion(blur)
blur = ndimage.binary_erosion(blur)
blur = ndimage.binary_erosion(blur)
blur = ndimage.binary_erosion(blur)

plt.imshow(final,'binary')
```

Before:

[image: Before]

---

After:

[image: After]

Comment: convert these masks to polygons and get the area.

Comment: how would you recommend? I am at a bit of a knowledge roadblock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use connectedComponentsWithStats function, this function return connected components and this area.